# What is Label Refinement in the Context of Image Segmentation

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have been reading the paper entitled [*Measures of Similarity*](https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub4/unnikrishnan_ranjith_2005_1/unnikrishnan_ranjith_2005_1.pdf) by Unnikrishnan and Herbet, in which they discuss some metrics to evaluate image segmentation. They use the word *refinement* of labels/segmentations/images in different places. However, it is unclear to me what this means, and an online search for "image refinement" does not bring much enlightenment.

I hope someone can elaborate a bit on the meaning of refinement in the context of images, or more specifically if possible, in the context of image segmentation.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems labeling is well presented in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/79314.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct context of the refinement key word is segmentation.

Label Refinement in the context of image segmentation is a step to increase the resolution and understanding of the segmentation.

It can be done by exterior knowledge (Like labels on features) or other optimization steps to have a better results of the segmentation (Which basically labeling of the image pixels).

For instance, if the segmentation is based on Super Pixels a Refinement Step could be merging of some Super Pixels.

You may have a look at [Label Refinement Network for Coarse to Fine Semantic Segmentation](https://vitalab.github.io/article/2018/11/22/Label-Refinement-Network.html). In this paper they use Multi Scale approach for label segmentation. By using coarse level to refine finder level.